# How do I set up my folder structure for parallel routes in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have:

```
-conversations
--layout.tsx
--[id]
----@list
------page.tsx
----@messages
------page.tsx
--page.tsx
```

My `layout.tsx` has:

```
// packages/webapp/src/app/(authenticated)/conversations/layout.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';
import PaperContainer from '@/app/_components/PaperContainer';

interface ConversationsLayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  list: React.ReactNode;
  messages: React.ReactNode;
}

const ConversationsLayout: React.FC<ConversationsLayoutProps> = ({ children, list, messages }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={5} md={3}>
        <PaperContainer sx={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}>
          {list}
        </PaperContainer>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={7} md={8} sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <PaperContainer sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', height: '100%' }}>
          {messages}
        </PaperContainer>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default ConversationsLayout;
```

Basically, if someone goes to `/conversations` or `/conversations/some-id`, I want this layout to load. How do I do this?

Comment: When user opens any page, the nearest layout should get loaded by default. I think your structure is good and should work. What happens exactly when you run this?